# Is it possible to set up a replicaset (mongo) with multiple application servers?

Tags: mongodb, server, cluster-computing, database

I want to set up a replicaset mongo architecture with 3 servers. My database is really small and no complex at all, so I just wan to optimize reading time. I am going to have a lot of concurrent connections, so I was wondering if instead of having one application server (I am currently using an Ubuntu server, my application use Django) that communicates with the 3 mongo instances (replicaset) I could have 2 application servers communicating with my mongo replicaset. Is this possible? Any hint on how to accomplish such configuration? Thanks a lot.  [(Image of wanted architecture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeyFB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course!  That is just normal situation. In real world, there is always more than one application server, serving customers and all of them are interacting with mongodb replicaset.

To archive situation where those app servers can talk more than only one (primary) you must "grant" applications to do that. Meaning "readPreference" settings, at least secondaryPreferred [explain here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/).